# How does Console.WriteLine() know how to convert an object to a string

Tags: c#, console-application

I am following the [Preamble: what is a reference type?](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html) where it explains parameters passing as value or reference type. The first example has the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Text;

public class Example1
{
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        StringBuilder first = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder second = first;
        first.Append ("hello");
        first = null;
        Console.WriteLine (second);
    }
}
```

And it does not provide the source code for the class (or struct) of StringBuilder, and I do not know how the Console.WriteLine(second) is able to return a string value just by using the identifier. Is it possible to return a value in the constructor?

I tried to write the class or struct by following (and it doesn't work):

```
struct StringBuilder
{
    private string _myString;
    public string StringBuilder
    {
        get { return _myString; }
        set { _myString = value; }
    }
    public void Append(string str)
    {
        _myString = str;
    }
}
```

Comment: StringBuilder is defined in the System.Text namespace.  I'm not sure why you are trying to redefine it.  Since you use the System.Text namespace in your program, you probably run into a naming collision.  What exactly does not work for you?

Comment: @EricJ. I'm new to .NET and C# and didn't know StringBuilder is a .NET class; so by reading the example I tried to write up the class. Anyway, I am still curious how the StringBuilder's object can be printed without call the ToString() method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look a the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swx4tc5e.aspx) for `Console.WriteLine(object value)`. It says this:

> the `ToString` method of value is called to produce its string
>   representation, and the resulting string is written to the standard
>   output stream.

So (as others have written), if you want to print a string representation of your own class or struct, you should override the [ToString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring.aspx) method.

Answer (score 4):

`StringBuilder` is .net class in `System.Text` namespace.

Comment: Correct, but doesn't answer the question

Answer (score 3):

Override [`ToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring) method for objects string representation.

```
public override string ToString()
{
  return _myString;
}
```

Or print out your property:

```
Console.WriteLine (second.StringBuilder);
```

Comment: Yes, this is the real answer to the OP's question. Every object in C# (and therefore every kind of variable, since everything inherits from Object) has a built in ToString function, which implicitly gets called in cased like this. See here for Object and its members: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object_members%28VS.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

`StringBuilder` is a `class`, not a `struct`. C# is not like C++ in this respect: the two are in fact different. And `Console.WriteLine(x)` where x is an arbitrary class ends up as `Console.WriteLine(x.ToString())`.

Comment: I didn't know StringBuilder is a .NET class. Anyway, I am still curious how calling the object itself can print out the string without calling method "ToString()"

Comment: @KMC: He just told you. When you call the `Console.WriteLine` function and pass in an arbitrary instance of a class, [that overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swx4tc5e.aspx) calls the `ToString` function in order to obtain a textual representation of the object.

Answer (score 2):

What the code does is to call `ToString` on the `StringBuilder` instance. The code gets clearer if you explicitly call `ToString` instead of letting it be called implicitly:

```
Console.WriteLine(second.ToString());
```

You can override the `ToString` method in your own class. You should use classes, by the way, only use structs if you have a specific need for it. Structs are more complicated to implement correctly.

Example:

```
class Example {

  public string Value { get; set; }

  public Example(string value) {
    Value = value;
  }

  public override string ToString() {
    return Value;
  }

}
```

Now the string value of your object will be its value:

```
Example ex = new Example("test");
Console.WriteLine(ex);
```