# How do I convert a System.Windows.Forms.Control into an integer in C#?

Tags: c#

I use Controls.Find to get the value of a textbox which I don't know the name of until runtime.  However the result returned by Controls.Find cannot seem to be converted into a string OR an integer (ERROR MSG:
CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Windows.Forms.Control' to 'string').  I thought that if I could convert it to string first then it wouldnt be a problem converting to integer but it wont even let me convert it to string.  Most mysteriously though, it prints this value to screen when I use Console.WriteLine(tbValue)!  Can anyone help?

```
        //This function takes the name of a textbox from an array and returns the value of it
        int GetDynamicTextboxValue(String tbName)
        {
            int value = 0;
            var matches = this.Controls.Find(tbName, true); //although matches is an array we are only expecting one result
            foreach (var tbValue in matches)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Dynamic textbox value = " + tbValue);
                value = Int32.Parse(tbValue);//This is where the conversion error occurs
            }
            return value;
        }
```

Comment: You don't. Controls aren't strings. If you want the control's value or text, use the correct properties

Comment: What are the correct properties?  textbox.Text?  I dont know the name of the textbox so I need to obtain the name of the textbox at runtime.  Why does it print the very value that I need through console.writeline yet I cant seem to extract that value any other way?

Comment: `What are the correct properties`...did you look in the documentation? Or tutorials? Or Examples?

Comment: If you know it's a TextBox, you can cast `tbValue` to the correct type. Some controls don't have a `Text` property though, eg a Numeric or DatetTimePickerr control provide their values directly

Comment: `Why does it print the very value that I need through console.writeline`..perhaps because it implicitly calls `ToString()`, which is adapted to return the value. But that won't happen automatically when you use Int32.parse.

Comment: P.S. If you know it's going to be a textbox you can Cast it from a Control, and then the properties exposed specifically by a textbox are explicitly available. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textbox?view=net-5.0 . P.P.S. We may be seeming a tiny bit frustrated here because the things you're asking about are largely described in the MS documentation or other places online already. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8709127/how-does-console-writeline-know-how-to-convert-an-object-to-a-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually have `Controls` collection at the moment which is the base class and of all the controls like `TextBox`, `Label`.

You will need to connvert the `Control` object to `TextBox` and then get the value from `Text` property of `TextBox` class something like:

```
foreach (var tbValue in matches)
{
     Console.WriteLine("Dynamic textbox value = " + tbValue);
     // cast the control as TextBox object
     var textBox = tbValue as TextBox;
     // if casting successful textBox will have reference to that textBox
     if(textBox !=null)
         value = Int32.Parse(textBox.Text);// now get the value of textbox and convert to integer
}
```

Comment: Thankyou Ehsan!  Thankyou for aiding my understanding in the form of a solution!  Others commenting on here need to understand that not everybody has the same understanding and comprehension of different languages.  I only started coding in C# this week and yes @ADyson I have read some of the online resource material but not being familiar with casting and a lot of the other things mentioned in there its like climbing a mountain for the first time..  but with the answer provided by Ehsan, this helps me a lot quicker to understand the problem.

Comment: @Helpme you are welcome, actually the documentation have all but as you said for a new bie it's sometimes not easy to just get it done by reading documentation but instead a working example helps more to understand how it will make sense, glad it helped